# Is it mandatory to create a TwiML app in order to receive calls?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Im starting to integrate Twilio into our app and we need to receive the inbound notifications from Twilio. I noticed that I can also set up the webhook url straight into the number.

So, my questions is? which is preferable? Set up the url into the number or direct into the TwiML app? The advantage I see is that I can add parameters straight into the number (One number, one campaign) instead of a single url for all my numbers.

Are there other considerations that I need to take in count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is not mandatory to create a TwiML app to receive calls, you can, as you say, set up a URL for each number you purchase.

TwiML apps do have benefits as you scale. For example, if you have multiple numbers, perhaps from different countries, which all point at the same URL, then using a TwiML app would mean that if you needed to change the URL in the future you could change it one place, not for every number. TwiML apps have the added benefit of a friendly name that you can use to describe what the URL does, rather than trying to guess from the URL itself.

The only downside to using a TwiML app that I can think of is that there is a level of indirection between what your number is doing and you have to go to the TwiML App section of the console when you are actively setting it up and experimenting.

My advice is that for short term experiments or work with single numbers to just use a URL and as you scale, move that to a TwiML app so that you can reap the benefits.

Let me know if that helps at all.